# Finding a string and the index of the string into list from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to find a string inside a txt file after converting it into a list and also I want to know the index of that string.

The txt file contain the following:

> ## captcp 2010-2013 Hagen Paul Pfeifer and others (c)
>
> ## http://research.protocollabs.com/captcp/
>
> ## total data (goodput): 33016186 byte (264.13 Mbit)
>
> ## throughput (goodput): 543805.43 byte/s (4.35 Mbit/s)

I tried the following code:

```
fo=open ('B_rand.txt', "r")
cont=fo.readlines()
print(cont)
if '4.35' in cont:
        print("yes:", cont.index('4.35')
 else:
        print("No")
```

Output: 
['# captcp 2010-2013 Hagen Paul Pfeifer and others (c)\n', '# http://research.protocollabs.com/captcp/\n', '# total data (goodput): 33016186 byte (264.13 Mbit)\n', '# throughput (goodput): 543805.43 byte/s (4.35 Mbit/s)\n']
No
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find.py", line 9, in 
    index = cont.index('4.35')
ValueError: '4.35' is not in list

I am expecting to find (4.35) with its index.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
You have not demonstrated any problem.

Comment: I added the problem. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You added part of the error message, and output that doesn't match your code.  I'll wait for you to finish the posting.

Comment: I added all of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.35 doesn't exist in your list, because it's checking the whole string against each element.  Instead, you want to search for that string in each list element.  For that, you can use any, and grab each element from the list as so:

```
if any("4.35" in el for el in cont):
```

If you just want to print the index in question,

```
print [i for i, el in enumerate(cont) if "4.35" in el]
```

Comment: It works to find the string. But how to know its index in the list?